# SSH connection ends after first exec()

Tags: node.js, ssh, promise

I'm writing a script to determine a remote server's OS, and, based on the result, run another command **only after** the first one (specific to the server's OS). I'm doing this through the `ssh2-promise` library (based on the original `ssh2`. First time `exec()` runs without any problems. Second time I call `exec()` on the same SSH connection, it closes and returns a `No response from server` error.

```
let myClass = new MyClass({
    host: "...",
    port: "...",
    username: "...",
    password: "..."
});

myClass.wrapper();


function MyClass(config) {
    let SSH = require('ssh2-promise');
    let connection = new SSH(config);

    function first() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.exec('some_command_to_exec')
                .then((data) => {
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }

    function second() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.exec('other_command_to_exec')
                .then((data) => {
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error);
                });
        });
    }

    this.wrapper = () => {
        first()
            .then((response) => {
                return second(response.connection);
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
}
```

Now I have tried not to reuse the same connection and open a new one on each `exec()`, like this:

```
function MyClass(config) {
    function first () {
        let connection = new SSH(config);
        //...
    }

    function second () {
        let connection = new SSH(config);
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

But the result's the same, the connection just closes. What can be the problem here? There is only one mention of this issue on `SSH2` library's Github, which yielded no useful result.

Comment: How did you observe the "No response from server" error?